# Reverse custom django Admin Site urls?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

Is there a way to reverse URLs added to a custom django AdminSite, for example

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyAdminSite, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'some_view/$',self.admin_view( SomeView.as_view()), name='some_view' ),
        )
        return my_urls + url

myadmin = MyAdminSite(app_name='my_admin')


url(r'^admin/', include(my_admin.urls)),
```

How do i reverse `some_view`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try: {% url admin:some_view %}

Comment: Great one, don't know why it didn't work before for me, probably an error on my part

Comment: They're a bit picky, but glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

alternatively, if you've defined a name for your admin site like so:

```
class ExplorerAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExplorerAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = 'explorer_admin'
        self.app_name = 'rql'

    def get_urls(self):
        parent_patterns = super(RQLExplorerAdmin, self).get_urls()
        dashboard_patterns = [
            url(r'^$', admin.site.admin_view(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='explorer.html')), name="explorer")
        ]
        return dashboard_patterns + parent_patterns
```

reversing the url would be done by applying namespacing using your custom sites' name, like so:

```
reverse('explorer_admin:explorer')
```